# How to custom indent json dump?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, dictionary

I use indent = 2, but I want the first level of indentation to be zero. For example:

**Partial Code**

```
json.dump(json_data, json_file, indent=2)
```

**Output**

```
{
  "a": 1,
  "b": "2",
  "list": [
    {
      "c": 3,
      "d": 4,
    }
  ]
}
```

**What I want instead**

```
{
"a": 1,
"b": "2",
"list": [
  {
    "c": 3,
    "d": 4,
  }
]
}
```

Comment: I'm really curious what's your use-case for this.

Comment: @yedpodtrzitko I am modifying JSONs for game modding purposes, it works but it would be better if it matches the native game JSON format

Comment: JSON is space-insensitive. Any good JSON parser should ignore spaces.

Comment: @DYZ I know that already, I specified in my previous comment that it works ingame, I just want the indentation for purely cosmetic purposes.

Comment: `json` module cannot do what you want. You will have to write your own pretty-printer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in the comments, it doesn't make functional difference and you will need custom pretty-print. something like

```
import json
import textwrap

spam = {"a": 1, "b": "2", 
        "list": [{"c": 3, "d": 4,}]}

eggs = json.dumps(spam, indent=2).splitlines()
eggs = '\n'.join([eggs[0], textwrap.dedent('\n'.join(eggs[1:-1])), eggs[-1]])
print(eggs)
with open('spam.json', 'w') as f:
    f.write(eggs)
```

output

```
{
"a": 1,
"b": "2",
"list": [
  {
    "c": 3,
    "d": 4
  }
]
}
```